# How can I rewrite this reduce function in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, reduce

I'm currently trying to convert some react native code to typescript, and there's a few reduce functions that are throwing errors. How can I rewrite this so that I do not have type issues when I run?

I've tried different ways of trying to type the function as well as the expected output, but no luck so far.

```
myArray: data.items.reduce( (map: object, obj: myInterface) : object  => { map[obj.id] = obj; return map; }, [])
```

the myArray item of my object should be populated with an array of items defined in myInterface. When I run I'm currently getting the following error.

```
TypeScript error in MyPath/:

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'number' can't be used to index type '{}'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'number' was found on type '{}'.  TS7053

    128 |                 appVersion: data.version || "",
    129 |                 offline: false,
    130 |                 myArray: data.items.reduce( (map: object, obj: myInterface) : object  => { map[obj.id] = obj; return map; }, [])
        |                                                                                           ^
    131 |             });
```

Comment: You cannot assign props to an object under these conditions. Try to replace `object` in `map: object` with this: `[propName: string]: any` like this: `map: {[propName: string]: any}`

Comment: Oh yeah that's bit of a problem too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Patrick Robert's answer fixed it. Thank you!

```
 myArray: data.items.reduce( (map: Record<myInterface['id'], myInterface>, obj: myInterface) : object  => { map[obj.id] = obj; return map; }, {})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your map is of type object. You have to provide an object as the initial value for the reduce function.

```
myArray: data.items.reduce(
   (map: Record<myInterface['id'], myInterface>, obj: myInterface): Record<myInterface['id'], myInterface>  => 
         { map[obj.id] = obj; return map; }, 
    {})
```

Comment: Declaring `map: Record<myInterface['id'], myInterface>` might be better, in case `id` is constrained more than `string | number | symbol`

Comment: yeah, that's type safe